# XMPP Chat server did not connected on iOS Device. while working perfectly on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp

I have created chat app for iOS using **XMPP and open fire server.** Its working perfectly few days earlier. Suddenly I am facing unexpected behaviour. My App is perfectly work on Simulator but does not connect on device.
I am using port **5222**.
I am getting following error when trying to connect on iOS device-:

```
[AppDelegate xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:] [Line 482] Error: Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB Code=8 "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" UserInfo=0x1658d9d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=nodename nor servname provided, or not known}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to fix this issues? am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes,I fixed this issue.  Check your network, your device and local server must be using same network. My Openfire server configure on my local machine that using different network while my devices using wifi that connected with different network.

Comment: How could you resolve this issues could you please help me ? i mean my iOS device uses wifi network connection and local server uses LAN connection.

Comment: Make sure both using same network, configure same DNS on device and LAN.

Answer (score -2):

In my case protocol was incorrect so i removed it and client redirected by nginx from `http` to `https` used just [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"my.server.url"];